# No mostrar teclado virtual - Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, teclado

Tengo un layout que es basicamente un formulario, y el primer control es un EditText por lo que el teclado virtual se muestra automáticamente en cuanto se abre el layout.

Hay alguna manera de que esto no ocurra?

Lo intento de esta forma pero no funciona:

```
private void GohideSoftKeyboard(Android.App.Activity activity)
        {
            var currentFocus = activity.CurrentFocus;
            if (currentFocus != null)
            {
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Desde donde llamas el método o como lo llamas?

Comment: En el OnResume() de esta forma:  base.OnResume();

                
                GohideSoftKeyboard(this);

Answer (score 0):

Llama tu método `hideSoftKeyboard()` :

```
 public void hideSoftKeyboard(Android.App.Activity activity)
    {
        var currentFocus = activity.CurrentFocus;
        if (currentFocus != null)
        {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        }
    }
```

Pero dentro de `OnCreate()` de esta forma:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  ...
  ...
  hideSoftKeyboard(this);
}
```